# Python- Aws Boto 3 Search for Subfolders from a Bucket/ Prefix with Unknown depth

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Given that I have an S3 Bucket with Multiple subfolders (with various depths).
Is it possible to recursively list all objects and their path based on a subfolder I am looking for?

For Example:

- Bucket: `DataLake-App`
- Prefix: `App1/2020/06/21/Timestamp/`
- Additional Subfolder path: `....../table_001/**.csv`

The .... is slightly unknown and can have an unknown depth

Given that I know the table, the Bucket, and the Prefix, is it possible for me to search subfolders if it contains the table name and gets all of its contents?

If so, what would that look like in AWS? I have been scratching my head for the last few hours on this. Any help/ideas would be great!!

Comment: Have you tried some code? Feel free to add it to your Question and let us know what specific problem you are having.

Answer (score 3):

The `list_objects_v2()` command in boto3 will return all objects in a bucket.

By specifying a `Prefix`, it will only return objects in the given path.

If you wish to do further manipulation, such as only finding objects with a Key ending with `/table_001/**.csv`, then this should be done in Python itself such as using `endswith()` or a regex search.

Please note that `list_objects_v2()` only returns 1000 objects at a time, so it might be necessary to use a [paginator](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html) or a loop using `ContinuationToken` to return all desired objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `resource` feature of the boto3 that wouldn't need to use the paginator.

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('my_bucket')

keys = 0

for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    
    keys += 1
    
    if keys > 10000: break
        
print(keys)

# 10001
```

By using this,

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('DataLake-App')

for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='App1/2020/06/21/Timestamp/'):
        
    if obj.key.endswith('.csv') and obj.key.split('/')[-1] == 'table_001':

        print(obj.key)
```

will give you the result.